# Numerically obtaining inverse 2D Laplace transform

Tags: numerics, integral-transforms

I wonder if there is a function in Mathematica (or code) that can help obtaining inverse 2D Laplace transform of a function, f(s1,s2) which is the 2D Laplace transform of a function F(t1,t2) in (s1,s2) domain.

Comment: Have you seen [`InverseLaplaceTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseLaplaceTransform.html)?

Comment: Read the Help under "LaplaceTransform": LaplaceTransform[expr,{Subscript[t, 1],Subscript[t, 2],\[Ellipsis]},{Subscript[s, 1],Subscript[s, 2],\[Ellipsis]}]
gives the multidimensional Laplace transform of expr.

Comment: I have already checked this function, however I have complex expression that may not be inverted using the table of Laplace transform. My question is how to obtained inverse 2D Laplace transform numerically (such as Stehfest algorithm for inverse 1D transform) @DanielHuber